# Can we remove the up-vote/down-vote buttons on locked posts?

Tags: feature-request, locked-posts

When a post has been locked and you try to vote on it, you get:

> This post has been locked; locked posts can't be voted on

So, can we just hide then or indicate disabled by showing a different shade?

Comment: I'm no UX expert but the UX people I work with tell me that's a terrible pattern since you risk that users never understand why a button or control is disabled or removed without the explicit feedback from an error message.

Comment: @ivarni we already do this for historically locked posts (or is it protected posts?), plus, the existing notice with the link should suffice: '*This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. A link to a chat room will be posted in the comments below if the conversation was moved to chat. [...]*'

Comment: Then those should be changed so they work like other locked posts. Same argument applies.